# Genymotion - VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion 2.8 and VirtualBox 5.1.6 on Windows 10.
When I try to start a VM with Genymotion, I always get the following error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSP3H.png)

I also tried running it directly from VirtualBox and I'm getting this error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdYEt.png)

Comment: try re-download images of android

Comment: Tried multiple times and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it by:

Opening Virtual Box ---> Select Android VM which you installed ---> Click right button ---> Click Settings ---> Go to Audio ---> Uncheck Enable Audio Checkbox